# How to implement "recalculate outside" in Blender

Tags: c++, cgal

When importing CAD file like STL format file, sometimes, some of the facets are reversed so their normal vectors are directing inside the volume while others going outside. the "recalculate outside" comes in to fix the situation.
But, I am wondering how I can implement the function with CGAL. It would be appreciated if some guy show me the way about hint or code snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Polygon Mesh Processing](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html) package introduced in CGAL 4.7 might help here.

In particular I think the function [`orient_polygon_soup()`](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PkgPolygonMeshProcessing.html#gab1ea30e030c62bf018afa4578d591f19) is what you need. Here is an [example](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2polygon_soup_example_8cpp-example.html) of how to use it.
You might also need the function [`polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh()`](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PkgPolygonMeshProcessing.html#gac8fe80db9800265922ce469c36d97baa)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did work. By the way, CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::is_outward_oriented(mesh) function looks like working for the closed surface.